# KeyError while trying to create a Column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column on an existing dataframe, but always having a "KeyError" problem.
In my dataframe, i have a column with the date of birth, and i want to use this column to get the age of a client.
The function that i use is

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
     df1['Idade'][i] = calculate_age(df1['Data de Nascimento'][i])
```

So far, there's nothing wrong with the function "calculate_age", but i always keep getting this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-79d009216c4d>", line 2, in <module>
    df1['Idade'][i] = calculate_age(df1['Data de Nascimento'][i])

  File "/home/mbarreto/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "/home/mbarreto/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Idade'
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to iterate over `df1['Idade']` but the column doesn't exist

Comment: You data frame does not have `Idade` column yet. So you cannot do, say, `df1['Idade'][0]`. What is your `calculate_age` function? You may be able to do just `df1['Idade'] = calculate_age(df1['Data de Nascimento'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to index on column that is not yet created

you need to do it like this

```py
df1['Idade'] = [calculate_age(df1['Data de Nascimento'][i]) for i in range(len(df1))]
```

or even cleaner

```py
df1['Idade'] = df1['Data de Nascimento'].apply(calculate_age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to loop over a column that doesn't exist yet hence the KeyError.

Here is an alternative way you would do it using the pandas datetime module;
Assuming the date of birth is a timestamp column in your dataframe (df1)

```py
year_now = pd.datetime.now()
df1['age'] = year_now.year - pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['dateofbirth']).year
```